# Animate ImageButton back to initial position

Tags: android, android-animation, animator, animatorset

I'm new to animations in android.
So, I have an ImageButton which I'm animating like this:

```
ObjectAnimator Y = ObjectAnimator.ofFloat(img, "y", 300f);
Y.setDuration(1000);
```

So, my ImageButton moves downward by this animation. How do I move it upwards(to its initial position) I tried `-y` as reverse of y but it's wrong syntax. So What's right syntax?

Answer (score 0):

ObjectAnimator Y = ObjectAnimator.ofFloat(img, "y", -300f);

There is no property named `-y`. y means the top-left position (x,y) of the view.

Comment: `-300f` moves it out of screen boundary. `-0.5f` works fine!
Thanks for assistance.

Comment: There's one more thing. I've an ImageButton on very Right of the screen. I want to animate it to center of screen. I tried: `ObjectAnimator Y = ObjectAnimator.ofFloat(img, "x", -300f);` . But the img moves to leftmost position of screen. Tried changing to `-0.1f`. No Success.